# Rails, change URL for a POST action within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, post, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I want the URL to be changed when a call to an action within the controller is made. My current scenario:

Controller:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        if city.blank?
            failure
        end
        ...
    end

    def failure
        ...
        render 'failure'
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
get '/event', to: 'event#index'
post '/event/failure' => 'event#failure'
```

But this code keeps the url as /events. The desired result is /events/failure

I've views for payment 'index' and 'failure'. I'm using rails ~ 5.0.0.

Comment: Is `event#failure` a POST or GET resource?

Comment: It is a post resource.

Comment: for you to change url, you will need to use `redirect_to` on a `GET` resource.

Comment: Is it possible to user redirect_to with a POST resource @kiddorails? (kindly asking)

Comment: no. it's not.
you can modify the route to accept both GET and POST for 'events#failure' and use redirect

Comment: But, redirect_to takes the controller anew. It reloads before_action and after_action. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Then you should check the purpose of `failure` action and maybe isolate GET and POST actions in different methods. I'm thinking about GET in sort of a static failure page and POST with some business logic on some payload. Please do not modify Rails by skipping callbacks and using same method to suit the need and in contrary, make your code follow the right restful conventions. :)

Comment: This is working fine, but trackers(ga) can't differentiate success and failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the URL to change you will want to do a redirect, something like this :

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        if city.blank?
            redirect_to action: 'failure'
        end
        ...
    end

    def failure
        ...
        render 'failure'
    end
end
```

But, redirection is not possible for POST requests as given in [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

You might want to consider changing your strategy.

Comment: But, redirect_to takes the controller anew. It reloads before_action and after_action. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You can add an `except` parameter to `before_action` and `after_action` that includes `failure`